# Using SwiftyJSON with Gmail API

Tags: swift2, gmail-api, swifty-json

I am trying to make a simple email app to learn how to work with REST API's like the Gmail API and Im using SwiftyJSON to work with the responses I get from my requests.

I'm trying to get who the sender of an email. Im using the following requests to get the message object back. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

From the JSON Data I need to go to the following path (payload>headers>from) to get who sent the message now I have tried all the ways that are specified on the github page.

```
//Getting a string using a path to the element
let path = [1,"list",2,"name"]
let name = json[path].string
//Just the same
let name = json[1]["list"][2]["name"].string
//Alternatively
let name = json[1,"list",2,"name"].string
```

All of these ways return null.

Now when i do the following i get the payload object of the message object in return

```
let from = json["payload"]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For those of us who are not familiar with the Gmail API, can you post the JSON response from Gmail?